# Custom update method in MVC 4 with WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, controller, updates

I am a newbie in MVC and currently using MVC 4 + EF Code First and WCF in my web project. Basically, in my project, WCF services will get the data from database for me, and it will take care of updating data as well. As a result, when I finish updating a record, I have to call the service client to make the change for me other than the "traditional" MVC way. Here is my sample code:

Model:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int ID{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Gender{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Birthday{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Detail(int ID, string name, string gender, DateTime birthday)
    {
        // get the WCF proxy
        var personClient = personProxy.GetpersonSvcClient();

        //update the info for a person based on ID, return true or false
        var result = personClient.Updateperson(ID, name, gender, birthday);

        if (result)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            //if failed, stay in the detail page of the person
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model Domain.person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Detail</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthday)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthday)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The controller is the part I am confused of. The Detail function takes multiple parameters, how can I call it from the View? Also, what should I put into this return field in the controller:

```
//if failed, stay in the detail page of the person
return View();
```

We usually put the model in, but the model seems to be not changed, since I am updating the database directly from my WCF service.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I know I can probably get it works by change the update method to take only one parameter which is the model itself, but this is not an option in my project.

Answer (score 0):

you call the Details action in the controller when you hit "Update"

//sidenote : use single parameter in your function that accepts the values it makes life easier

Comment: I agree, but that's not an option in my case. Is that any other way to make it work?

Comment: I can't imagine why shouldn't that be an option , can you elaborate on that ?

Answer (score 0):

The form will call the post method in the controller that has the same name as the get method that rendered the view when it is submitted.

You can alter this default behavior by specifying parameters in the `BeginForm` method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController"))
```

Also, you are using a strongly typed view (good!), so you can change the signature of your post method to accept the model object

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Detail(Person person)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I forgot to mention that my post method has the same name as the get method, just has more parameters. Also, as I mentioned in the last update in my post,public ActionResult Detail(Person person) is not an option. the problem I am having is that my post method needs multiple parameters, and I don't know how to pass those parameter from the view.